# can i use Veremi dataset for Flying ad-hoc networks?

Tags: database, security

I have a question about VEREMI Database.  It is made for vehicular networks misbehavior detection and it is generated using veins.
I want to use it for flying ad-hoc networks because I didn't find a similar dataset for drones generated by AVENS can i use it?

i try to generate another dataset from omnet++ and avens but it's very difficult because I don't know how to extract the event log file from omnnet++